# convert html report generated by protractor-html-screenshot-reporter into excel

Tags: protractor

I am using protractor-html-screenshot-reporter to generate an HTML report, I want it to be converted/exported into an excel sheet. How do I do that ?
Can someone help me out with this ?

Comment: find & try npm package which can write excel to output the html report into excel file.

Answer (score 0):

From their Documentation:

> On running the task via grunt, screenshot reporter will be generating
>   json and png files for each test.
>
> Now, you will also get a summary report, Stack trace information also.
>
> With this postprocessing, you will get a json which has all the
>   metadata, and also an html page showing the results.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-html-screenshot-reporter#html-reporter

Now these Json can easily converted to Excel https://json-csv.com/